# Corfu: Why does <tab> shows a corfu popup?

Tags: key-bindings, corfu

I have this configuration:

```lisp
(setq tab-always-indent 'complete)
(global-corfu-mode 1)
```

Nothing else should have grabbed the `<tab>` key. When I do `C-h k`, then `<tab>`, I get that it is bould to `indent-for-tab-command`. Reading the source, it seems to call `completion-at-point` given my config. However, I still see a corfu popup.

Reading `corfu.el`, I do not understand how it is remapping `<tab>` to display a corfu popup.

Comment: This is the expected behavior for what you've described.  Do you want to change the behavior in some way, or are you just curious about how it works?

Comment: I was just curious. I found out and posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`indent-for-tab-command` calls `completion-at-point` which calls `completion-in-region` which behaves according to `completion-in-region-function`. When `corfu-mode` is on, this variable is set to `#corfu--in-region`. This explains why `<tab>` displays a corfu popup.